# How do I click a link on a Cloud Saas app with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to automate some data entry and testing on Oracle Cloud Saas ERP app with puppeteer.

Here are the steps and code. The problem I have is whenever I execute the page.click on an element I get the error:

```
(node:58569) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'a#pt1:commandLink1.xj8.xit' is not a valid selector.
    at <anonymous>:1:33
    at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle (/Users/user/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:88:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
(node:58569) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:58569) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Open Login page and Login to App (Works)

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(config.appurl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.type('#userid', 'USERNAME', {delay : 10});
  await page.type('#password', 'PASSWORD', {delay : 10});
  await page.waitForSelector('#btnActive', {enabled : true});
  page.click('#btnActive', {delay : 1000}).then(() => console.log('Login Button Clicked'));
```

Log urls on Target Changed (Works)

```
browser.on('targetchanged', ()=> {
    console.log('Target Changed!');
    console.log('URL: ', page.url());
  });
```

Render, Screenshot and Click an element on home page load (The Render and Screenshot works as expected. I see the screenshot and rendered html is for the homepage after the user has logged in but the clicks generate the error - not a valid selector)

```
page.on('load',()=> {
    console.log('Home Page Loaded!');
    console.log(page.url());
    page.screenshot({path: 'home.png'});
    async function render(page){
      let html = await page.content();
      await fs.writeFileSync('home.html', html);
    }
    render(page);
    page.click('a#pt1:commandLink1.xj8.xit', {delay : 1000}).then(() => console.log('Link Clicked')); //this is what generates the error
  });
```

From the rendered content of the homepage I see the html snippet below which is what I am trying to click using page.click.

```
<div><a id="pt1:commandLink1" class="xj8 xit" onclick="return false;" href="#">You have a new home page!</a></div>
```

Another problem I see using puppeteer and chrome to write scripts on Cloud Saas App is that I cannot use Inspect Element on all elements on the page, not sure why.

How do I change my script so I am able to click the link mentioned on this page?

Comment: It says: `'a#pt1:commandLink1.xj8.xit' is not a valid selector` Have you checked this selector?

Comment: Hi @vaviloff inspect element does not work on this element. I am inferring the selector from the rendered html I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Vaviloff No not yet. Any ideas?